# Returning lines that differ between two files (Python)

Tags: python, file, lines

I have two files with tens of thousands of lines each, output1.txt and output2.txt. I want to iterate through both files and return the line (and content) of the lines that differ between the two. They're mostly the same which is why I can't find the differences (filecmp.cmp returns false).

Comment: Do you want to compare the `i`th line of each file or do you want to find lines in each file that don't exist anywhere in the other?

Comment: If you're only doing this once or twice it might be easier to just use GitHub with it's nice shiny interface

Comment: Do you have an example of the output you want? Similar to `diff`?

Comment: Suppose `output1.txt` is 10,000 lines and `output2.txt` is 10,001 lines long. They are exactly the same except the insertion of a single line half way through. How would you envision that this would be shown to the user?

Comment: If you can use linux/unix, `diff` might help.

`diff output1.txt output2.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import difflib, sys

tl=100000    # large number of lines

# create two test files (Unix directories...)

with open('/tmp/f1.txt','w') as f:
    for x in range(tl):
        f.write('line {}\n'.format(x))

with open('/tmp/f2.txt','w') as f:
    for x in range(tl+10):   # add 10 lines
        if x in (500,505,1000,tl-2):
            continue         # skip these lines
        f.write('line {}\n'.format(x))        

with open('/tmp/f1.txt','r') as f1, open('/tmp/f2.txt','r') as f2:
    diff = difflib.ndiff(f1.readlines(),f2.readlines())    
    for line in diff:
        if line.startswith('-'):
            sys.stdout.write(line)
        elif line.startswith('+'):
            sys.stdout.write('\t\t'+line)
```

Prints (in 400 ms):

```
- line 500
- line 505
- line 1000
- line 99998
        + line 100000
        + line 100001
        + line 100002
        + line 100003
        + line 100004
        + line 100005
        + line 100006
        + line 100007
        + line 100008
        + line 100009
```

If you want the line number, use enumerate:

```
with open('/tmp/f1.txt','r') as f1, open('/tmp/f2.txt','r') as f2:
    diff = difflib.ndiff(f1.readlines(),f2.readlines())    
    for i,line in enumerate(diff):
        if line.startswith(' '):
            continue
        sys.stdout.write('My count: {}, text: {}'.format(i,line))
```

Answer (score 4):

### 7.4. [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) — Helpers for computing deltas

New in version 2.1.

This module provides classes and functions for comparing sequences. It can be used for example, for comparing files, and can produce difference information in various formats, including HTML and context and unified diffs. For comparing directories and files, see also, the filecmp module.

Comment: I can never understand official docs. Is there an easy to understand example that does what I am looking for?

Comment: There are some examples further down the docs page. Read them, and even more importantly, try things out in the Python interpreter! There is also the Python Module Of The Week (MOTW) site, which has some [more examples of difflib](http://pymotw.com/2/difflib/).

Comment: I scrolled down these examples and none of them technically apply to what I am looking for. Thanks though!

Comment: @user2597879, maybe you can give some short samples, and how you would like the difference to be shown

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't care about order you could use:

```
with open('file1') as f:
    t1 = f.read().splitlines()
    t1s = set(t1)

with open('file2') as f:
    t2 = f.read().splitlines()
    t2s = set(t2)

#in file1 but not file2
print "Only in file1"
for diff in t1s-t2s:
    print t1.index(diff), diff

#in file2 but not file1
print "Only in file2"
for diff in t2s-t1s:
    print t2.index(diff), diff
```

Edit:
If you do care about order and they're mostly the same then why not just use the command `diff`?

Comment: if the lines are sufficiently long, the `set` population could kill the system memory

Comment: I found the differences using this method but have no idea what lines they occur on