# Comparing two files of jsons and resulting json difference

Tags: python, json, file, comparison

I am trying to compare two files and each line is in JSON format. I need to compare each line between two files and should return the difference.Since the file size is too big and I am unable to read and compare each line.Please suggest me some optimised way in doing this.

Comment: Possible repeat question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799680/returning-lines-that-differ-between-two-files-python

Comment: @Josh, not really a duplicate, but that may help if the json is nicely and consistently formatted

Answer (score 3):

Two possible ways :

1. Using the technique mentioned in the comment posted by Josh.
2. Using the technique mentioned here :
   [how to compare 2 json in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141644/how-to-compare-2-json-in-python).

Given that you have a large file, you are better off using difflib technique described in point 1.

**Edit based on response to my below answer**:

After some research, it appears that the best way to deal with large data payloads is to process this payload in a streamed manner. This way we ensure a speedy processing of the data keeping in mind the memory usage and performance of the software in general.

Refer to [this](http://www.enricozini.org/2011/tips/python-stream-json/) link that talks about Streaming JSON data objects using Python. Similarly take a look at [ijson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/) - this is an iterator based JSON parsing/processing library in python.

Hopefully, this helps you towards identifying a good fit library that will solve your use case

Comment: Thanks. But i have thousands of lines and inner values of jsons need not be in same order in both files.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a pretty solid start: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/jsondiff

```
>>> pip install jsondiff
>>> from jsondiff import diff
>>> diff({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'b': 3, 'c': 4}, syntax='symmetric')
{insert: {'c': 4}, 'b': [2, 3], delete: {'a': 1}}
```

I'm also going to try it out for a current project, I'll try to maintain updates and edits as I go along.